# How can I show the last workflow participant?

Tags: workflow, task-list, approval-process

I need to have a field in the task list that shows me the last user that has participated in the workflow. I need it to know who the task is coming from. I need to show the user that delegated it or in the case that the task will be generated by a previous approval, see the user who made the approval. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

Just capture the SharePoint default field - **"Modified By"**. This will be applicable to all workflows, be it SharePoint Designer workflows or the likes of Nintex, K2 etc.

Comment: In my case that does not work since the modified field always shows me the system account and not who approves the task. 
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What workflow are you using? Can you share some more details of the workflow logic

Comment: I'm using a reusable workflow and it's a Sharepoint 2010 workflow. And it's the standard approval workflow.

Comment: Let me research on it a bit more, and then I'll get back to you. Please check back on this thread soon, if I don't reply

Comment: In the end I have achieved a solution through an external process. First I have created a field in which to store the name of the person who generated the task. To fill this field the process identifies the previous task and takes the value of the AssignedTo field and inserts it in the new field of the current task.

Comment: a smart solution